# Authentication levels for secure access to secure website areas with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Good morning

I have been working on this e-commerce website, one of the requirements is the implementation of different SESSION to grant the access to secure areas only to the authorised Users, for instance, only the Admin will haver access to the Admin area.

While the authentication works, it seems that only the user SESSION is implemented at this stage, this is the code for the authentication.php page:

```
<?php
    //start session management
    session_start();
    //connect to the database
    require('connection.php');
    //retrieve the functions
    require('../model/functions_members.php');
   
   
    //retrieve the username and password entered into the form
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password']; 
    $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
    $lastId = $stmt->fetchColumn();
    $userID = $lastId;

    //call the retrieve_salt() function
    $result = retrieve_salt($username);
        
    //retrieve the random salt from the database
    $salt = $result['salt'];
    //generate the hashed password with the salt value
    $password = hash('sha256', $password.$salt); 
        
    //call the login() function
    $count = login($username, $password);

    //query the database
    $sql = "SELECT userType FROM sport_cars.user WHERE userID = '.$userID.'";
    //prepared statement
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    foreach ($result as $row) :
        $userType = $row['userType'];    
    endforeach;

        
     //if there is one matching record
     if($count == 1 && $userType = 'User')
     { 
         //start the user session to allow authorised access to secured web pages
         $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
         //if login is successful, create a success message to display on the products page
         $_SESSION['success'] = 'Hello ' . $username . '. Have a great day!';
         //redirect to products.php
         header('location:../index.php');
     }
     elseif($count == 1 && $userType = 'Admin')
     {
           //start the admin session to allow authorised access to secured web pages
           $_SESSION['admin'] = $admin;
           //if login is successful, create a success message to display on the products page
           $_SESSION['success'] = 'Hello ' . $username . '. Have a good day!';
           //redirect to products.php
           header('location:../index.php');
     }
     elseif($count == 1 && $userType = 'Disabled')
     {
        
              //start the disabled session to allow authorised access to secured web pages
         $_SESSION['disabled'] = $disabled;
         //if login is successful, create a success message to display on the products page
         $_SESSION['success'] = 'Hello ' . $username . '. Have a great day!';
         //redirect to products.php
         header('location:../index.php');
        
     }
     else 
     {
         //if login not successful, create an error message to display on the login page
         $_SESSION['error'] = 'Incorrect username or password. Please try again.';
         //redirect to login.php
         header('location:../members.php');
     }

 ?>
```

After commenting out the second part of the code for debugging, I noticed the following error: [Error within authentication.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5W9G.png)

This part of the code is what I am using to ensure that the Admin is the only User able to access the Admin page:

```
<?php
            require_once("controller/connection.php");

            if( isset($_SESSION['admin'])) { 
                // grant access
              } else { 
                //redirect 
                header('location:members.php');
              }
   ?>
```

This is the code for function_members.php if that helps:

```
<?php

//create a function to retrieve salt

function retrieve_salt($username)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM games_hub.user WHERE username = :username";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetch();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $result;
}

//create a function to login
function login($username, $password)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM games_hub.user WHERE username = :username AND password = :password ";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $statement->bindValue(':password', $password);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    $count = $statement->rowCount();    
    return $count;
}
?>

<!-- create a function to add a new user -->
<?php
function add_user($username, $password, $salt, $first_name, $last_name, $email)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO games_hub.user (username, password, salt, first_name, last_name, email) VALUES (:username, :password, :salt, :first_name, :last_name, :email)";
    $statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bindValue(':username', $username);
    $statement->bindValue(':password', $password);
    $statement->bindValue(':salt', $salt);
    $statement->bindValue(':first_name', $first_name);
    $statement->bindValue(':last_name', $last_name);
    $statement->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $result = $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $result;  
    
    }
?>
```

Thanks for your help in advance, I have been trying to achieve this for a few days.

Comment: In your `if` statements you are **assigning** a value to `$userType` instead of **comparing**. Is this what you want? E.g. `$count == 1 && $userType = 'User'` checks that `$count` is equal to `1`, but does not check that `$userType` is equal to `'User'`. It merely checks that `$userType` does not contain a _falsy_ value after assigning the value `'User'` to it (which is always true). Consider using comparison operators instead of assignment operators. For example `$userType === 'User'`.

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT userType FROM sport_cars.user WHERE userID = '.$userID.'";` is insecure. Your passwords also should be hashed with the newer hash/verify functions. https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php